# Calling EJB from war client

Tags: ejb

I have my application ear .Now inside this ear I have two parts .
First EJB module 
Second Web Module packaged inside the war. So my Ear root looks like

EAR

---EJB Modules

---WAR Modules

Now I have a requirement to call one of the ejb from one of the war client. Is there any way other than remote EJB call to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class WarManagedBean{
    @EJB
    private EjbBean ejbBean;

    public void method(){
        //Using of EJB
    }
}
```

Comment: For this to implement do I need to do any configuration changes in any of the file like web.xml

Comment: No, you don't. Only CDI support is required.